# How do I retrieve column content?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to get content of a field with queryset command 'Post.objects.values('country__name')' and I am getting following error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'cities' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts\\/cabinet\\/cities\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

Although I don't get any error when I type this command in django shell.

my view:

```
def home(request):
        user = User.objects.all()
        cname = request.POST.get('dropdown1')
        city = Post.objects.all().distinct('city')
        country = Post.objects.values('country__name')
        print(country)
        context = {
            'country': country,
            'user': user,
            'city': city
        }

        return render(request, 'registration/home.html', context)
```

my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:blog')
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/', views.profile, name='cabinet'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/countries/', views.countries, name='countries'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/cities/<int:pk>/', views.cities, name='cities'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/address/<int:pk>/', views.address, name='address'),



]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a [`NoReverseMatch` error.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/) That means the problem is with your urls.

It says you're trying to access `path('accounts/cabinet/cities/<int:pk>/', views.cities, name='cities'),`, but you aren't giving the `<int:pk>` argument for it.

Check the template you're trying to load, and make sure it contains that argument in your `{% url 'cities' arg1 %}` block.

Comment: I tried `country.pk` as an arg1. But I still get NoReverseMatch erorr

Comment: Put your template up and tell me here. I'll check it then.